# A script that works on a local computer but not the server

Tags: php, gallery, localhost, wamp

I have found a very good gallery (EasyGallery) script that I integrated into my website and it was working fine on the wamp server on my computer. However, when I uploaded it to my web hosting (paid, supports php, databases etc) the script would not load. I tried 3 different web hostings both the original version of the script and modified version that I integrated into my website.

So my question is why the gallery script that can be found here http://www.freitagmorgen.de/#/
works with WAMP on my computer but does not work on the servers.

---

PHP versions:

Paid Hosting - PHP Version 5.2.17
Wamp - 5.3.13
Other Web Hostings - 5+ (correct ones)

Required by the script: 4+

---

Regarding the instruction on their website:
I have set the right permissions for Pictures folder (+subfolders) - 0755

---

the address of the website and the gallery is http://dmbathrooms.co.uk/test/gallery.php#/

it can read the styles bit, hence the grey background but not the rest

Comment: Version of PHP? PHP Configuration? File/directory permissions? Check server logs

Answer (score 2):

By far the most likely cause is that there is a relative/absolute path issue, so on your local computer it works but when put online the paths are computed incorrectly. Without code or a link to the broken page I can't say just what path is set incorrectly, but this is an extremely common cause of problems when going from localhost development to publishing a website online.

The other most common cause is directory permissions, as this is almost never an issue on localhost and almost always an issue on a hosted server. That's something that only you can check, however.

Comment: I thought the problems was to do with permissions but as I said I have  set it to 0755 for the Pictures folder. Still the same

Answer (score 0):

From the same website:

```
INSTALLATION

    Extract and copy to your Webserver
    Make the PICTURES/ folder writeable (chmod 775)
    Copy your images to the PICTURES/ folder

You need a Webserver with at least PHP 4 installed.
```

check php version on your server.

Comment: versions are correct on all of he 3 servers with gd library support for thumbnail generation etc